# Any way to retrieve SQL Server Job Agent Job's Settings from the past?

Tags: sql, settings, jobs, agent

Tool settings:
MS SQL Management Studio 2005-build 9.00.5000.00
.NET 2.05
OS 5.2

Genereic OS:
MS Server 2003
x64
SP2

Issue:
Changed the jobs schedule from weekly to daily on Tuesday. On Monday the report worked fine. But since then it does not generate a front end report so on Tuesday and Wednesday till now there are no daily reports..

Question: How do I get a view/log of the exact settings that were set for this job on Monday or before Monday but not any settings newer than Monday?

I do not want large tasks such as pulling the tapes with the DBA guys! ;)

Who is a DBA genius out there?

Answer (score 0):

> I do not want large tasks such as pulling the tapes with the DBA guys! ;)

Oops.

You need the `msdb` backup to restore as "msdbold" or such. 
Then you query the job tables.

If you do not want to restore, or can't, then there is **no** historical data

It is a simple, binary choice

Comment: Ohh damn it. Thanks for letting me know gbn, this is what one of the DBA's suggested here but don't want it to be a chore in the afternoon. But pulling tapes in an afternoon could be fun if BAU is quiet! Had some rice and had a thought, I think the issue could be that another job/setting or rdl in ms sql that could run on Sunday then triggers this Monday job. Or this Monday job is embedded in another job (daily/weekly/monthly). I am sure the history could help, but checking this Jobs history Monday isn't there!

Comment: I have checked the right click on job View History and filtered for 04.08.2014. Is the history not getting saved longer than 2days or is there other places to check history of this jobs execution?

Comment: History of a job is *not* settings. You need a restore.

Comment: Its a Subscription and its settings in this tool called SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS). I went in there and followed it step by step in the procedure steps and saw that only Monday at 0700 was set. For a test I set it to 13.50 and the user got his report. Does this mean I can now add SSRS on my CV? ;)